# How to set value of dynamic cascading drop downs in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on an Angular 6 application which uses reactive forms. In a form, I have a drop down list for regions which gets populated based on the selected value in another drop down list for countries. The issue is, when the value of country list is set while displaying the data fetched from the database, its change event is fired (which loads the regions for the selected country). This change event is not finished before it tries to set the region value for the edited record and therefore, the correct value of the region is never set.

Below is my code:

```
constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataservice: DataService
)
{
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        country: [null],
        region: [null]
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {

this.form
      .get("country")!
      .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe(countryName => {

            this.form.patchValue({
              region: null
            });

            this.loadRegions(countryName);
      });

this.loadCountriesList();

this.loadData();

}

private loadCountriesList() {
    this.countriesList = [];

    this.dataservice.getCountries().subscribe((countries) => {
        this.countriesList = countries;

        if (countries.length > 0) {
            this.form.controls["country"].setValue("US");
        }

    });
}

private loadRegions(countryName: string) {
    this.regions = [];

    this.dataservice
        .getRegions(countryName)
        .subscribe((regions) => {
            this.regions = regions;
        });
}

loadData(){
    this.dataservice.getRecord(5).subscribe(data => {
        this.form.patchValue({
            country: data.countryName;
            region: data.region; //Problem: the value of the region is not set here
        });
    });
}
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is any alternate/better way of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put this.loadCountriesList() and this.loadData(); bellow directly this.loadRegions(countryName);

```
ngOnInit(): void {

   this.form
  .get("country")!
  .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(200))
  .subscribe(countryName => {

        this.form.patchValue({
          region: null
        });

        this.loadRegions(countryName);
        this.loadCountriesList();
        this.loadData();
  });



 }
```